# How to integrate Affiliate API's into website

Tags: api, integration

How to integrate affiliate APIs into my site, basically a script that can upload affiliate, create pages accordingly with product names,specifications, and update prices.
Can I do it using some CMS like magento.
If there is any raw script available please share.